# Combine 2 related DataFrames into one multiple indexes dataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've 2 related Data Frames, Is there any easy way to combine into multi-indexes dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( [[
   1,0,1,0],
    [1,1,0,0],
    [1,0,0,1],
  [0,1,0,1]], columns=["c1","c2","c3", "c4"]
 )
idx= pd.Index(['p1','p2','p3','p4'])
df = df.set_index(idx)
```

df output is:

```
    c1  c2  c3  c4
p1  1   0   1   0
p2  1   1   0   0
p3  1   0   0   1
p4  0   1   0   1
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame( [[
   0,10,30,0],
    [20,10,0,0],
    [0,10,0,6],
  [15,0,18,5]], columns=["c1","c2","c3", "c4"]
 )
idx2= pd.Index(['a1','a2','a3','a4'])
df2 = df2.set_index(idx2)
```

df2 output is:

```
    c1  c2  c3  c4
a1  0   10  30  0
a2  20  10  0   0
a3  0   10  0   6
a4  15  0   18  5
```

The final dataframe is multi-indexing (p,c,a) single column (value):

```
            value
p1  c1  a2  20
        a4  15
    c3  a1  30
        a4  18
p2  c1  a2  20
        a4  15
    c2  a1  10
        a2  10
        a3  10
p3  c1  a2  20
        a4  15
    c4  a3  6
        a4  5
p4  c2  a1  10
        a2  10
        a3  10
    c4  a3  6
        a4  5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape an `merge`:

```
(df.reset_index().melt('index')
   .loc[lambda x: x.pop('value').eq(1)]
   .merge(df2.reset_index().melt('index').query('value != 0'),
          on='variable')
   .set_index(['index_x', 'variable', 'index_y'])
   .rename_axis([None, None, None])
)
```

output:

```
          value
p1 c1 a2     20
      a4     15
p2 c1 a2     20
      a4     15
p3 c1 a2     20
      a4     15
p2 c2 a1     10
      a2     10
      a3     10
p4 c2 a1     10
      a2     10
      a3     10
p1 c3 a1     30
      a4     18
p3 c4 a3      6
      a4      5
p4 c4 a3      6
      a4      5
```

If order matters:

```
(df.stack().reset_index()
   .loc[lambda x: x.pop(0).eq(1)]
   .set_axis(['index', 'variable'], axis=1)
   .merge(df2.reset_index().melt('index').query('value != 0'),
          on='variable', how='left')
   .set_index(['index_x', 'variable', 'index_y'])
   .rename_axis([None, None, None])
)
```

output:

```
          value
p1 c1 a2     20
      a4     15
   c3 a1     30
      a4     18
p2 c1 a2     20
      a4     15
   c2 a1     10
      a2     10
      a3     10
p3 c1 a2     20
      a4     15
   c4 a3      6
      a4      5
p4 c2 a1     10
      a2     10
      a3     10
   c4 a3      6
      a4      5
```